# "On the utility of Latin" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

What would be the best translation of "On the utility of Latin" into (ciceronian) Latin?
Specifically as a title (e.g., of a blog article).

I am open to loose translations, here are some ideas I came up with:

- Cur lingua latina discenda est?
- De utilitate linguae latinae

What do you think? Maybe an indirect question would be a better fit.

Comment: I like "Cur lingua latina discenda est?" YouTube is full of "Why should learn(such language)?"

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for your comment, I was afraid a direct question as a title didn't sound great in Latin

Comment: I should note though that Youtube is not particularly Ciceronian...

Comment: I tend to see indirect questions rather than direct questions as section headings, so I'd recommend *Cur lingua latina discenda sit* over *est*. I think there's an implied *tractatur* or *rogabitur* vel sim.

Comment: *De utilitate linguae Latinae* sounds perfectly good and *satis tullianum* to me; you would [not be the first](https://www.google.de/books/edition/De_latin%C3%A6_lingu%C3%A6_utilitate_oratio/YM9lAAAAcAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PP5&printsec=frontcover) to use that title, though.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel If you want to write that up as an answer, I have an upvote waiting. That's exactly the way I'd phrase it.